# inserting structure elements into database

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am looping through an array of structures as follows:

```
<cfloop array="#cfData#" index="i">
  <cfif structKeyExists(i, "date")>
    <cfset counter++>
   <cfoutput>#counter#</cfoutput> Date  is: <cfoutput> #i.date#</cfoutput> <br/>
  </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

Now, I have to insert the values of Date and other keys into my database and I am attempting it like the following:

```
<cfquery datasource="mydb" dbname="Stats">
    INSERT INTO mydatabase
    VALUES  
       <cfif structKeyExists(cfData, "date")>
           <cfset counter++>#cfData.date#
       </cfif>
       ,
       <cfif structKeyExists(cfData, "delivered")>
           <cfset counter1++>
           #cfData.delivered#
       </cfif>
       ,
       ... and so on for other key values...
  </cfquery>
```

Is that a correct way of inserting it into the MySQL database?

P.S: You can also refer to my previous thread for more information:

[Checking for key existence in structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439794/checking-for-key-existence-in-structure)

UPDATE:

Actually, in order to avoid the columlist mismatch, I decided to test it as following

```
<cfset KeyList   = "delivered,
                    unique_open,
                    spamreport,
                    drop,
                    request,
                    bounce,
                    deferred,
                    processed,
                    date,
                    startdate,
                    enddate,
                    open,
                    blocked">

<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen#" index="i">

        <cfloop list="#KeyList#" index="colItem">    
        <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "colItem")>
        <cfoutput>#cfData[i].colItem#</cfoutput>

      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>
        <cfif colItem neq listLast(KeyList)>,</cfif> 
    </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
```

Still it shows NULL in the browser.

However, when I test it like the following , I get correct results  for delievered: 5 NULL 12 2 1 12 1

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen#" index="i">


        <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "delivered")>
        <cfoutput>#cfData[i].delivered#</cfoutput>

      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>


    </cfloop>
```

What's wrong with using KeyList elements ?

Comment: not really no.  looks like you need to brush up on SQL syntax for inserts.  Also, use `<cfqueryparam ... />` don't just pass those values into the query directly.

Comment: @SeanCoyne What wrong I am doing in SQL Insert Syntax? Source:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html Somehow I will ave to check the existence of keys and that's why I did what I mentioned

I am aware of <cfqueryparam> which I will use in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @user3239126 you need to have `()` around your values i.e. `values (1,2,3)`

Comment: @user3239126 - Sean was referring to the fact that the code above will not produce a valid SQL statement. But before we even get to that, you need to explain the relationships between the data in your structure and your db table. (At this point we do not even know your table structure). Using [the dump in your other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439794/checking-for-key-existence-in-structure), what records *should* be inserted into your db table - and why? Feel free to use http://sqlfiddle.com to show us the table structure and expected result.

Comment: @Leigh Got you. I used sqlfiddle to define here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e255c/1

However, I wanna insert the elements that I have grabbed from the array of structures instead of hardcoding the values. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very bad way of inserting data.  An sql insert statement looks like this:

```
insert into mytable
(field1, field2, etc)
values
(value1, value2, etc)
```

and each specified field needs a matching value.  Also, each value needs a matching field.

There is this alternative:

```
insert into mytable
values
(value1, value2, etc)
```

But, if you do that you need a value for every field in the table.

You have conditional logic in the values part of your query.  If any of your cfif block returns false, you have at least one and possibly two problems.  You will definitely have a mismatch between the number of fields and number of values.  You will possibly have an extra comma.  Either will cause your query to crash.

I think you need a different approach.  cfquery has a null attribute that you can use in your conditional logic.  I'll let you think about that for awhile.

Comment: Thanks. I know how Insert statement works. Please refer to my recent post corresponding to Leigh's advise. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based upon the array of struts linked to in the question being the data inserted

If you know your expected struct values and name your column names are the same, this would be one solution:

```
<!--- set your column names in a list --->
<cfset columnList = "date,delivered,open,processed,request,unique_open">

<cfquery datasource="mydb" dbname="Stats">
INSERT INTO mydatabase (#columnList#)
VALUES
  <!--- loop through your array --->
   <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(cfData)#" index="i">
   (
    <!--- loop through the list of columns and see if they exists in the struct --->
    <cfloop list="#columnList#" index="colItem">
      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], colItem)>
        <cfqueryparam value="#cfData[i][colItem]#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>
        <cfif colItem neq listLast(columnList)>,</cfif>
    </cfloop>
    )<cfif i neq arrayLen(cfData)>,</cfif>
  </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

Also in this format i would suggest using `#createODBCDate()#` before inserting the dates

Comment: I suggest moving all the conditional logic out of the sql string.  It would make the "when in doubt look at your data" approach to troubleshooting a lot easier.  Also, the attribute is called null, not isnull.

Comment: Thanks Dan, as for moving the conditional logic outside of the query, i don't believe you can use <cfqueryparam> tags outside a <cfquery> so i left that part alone. However, i do agree it may make debugging a little more difficult. Also, thanks for the fix on "isNull"

Comment: You can't use cfqueryparams outside a query, but you can set variables to be used in the null attributes.

Comment: It just occurred to me that if the struct item did not exists it would have errored on evaluating the "value" of the <cfqueryparam> so i changed it to make it work.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help. But for some reason,it's only inserting NULL in each and every columns. I am wondering why?

Comment: I tried it with some sample data and had no problem, do the struct keys match the "columnList" items?

Comment: The problem I see here is the "columnList" items. They are like as follows: delivered_int, unique_open_int,drop_int etc, however, while referring to structure keys, we just need delivered, unique_open etc So, I will have to maintain something like "KeyList" for looping list items

Comment: @ssteinbeck Could you please check my updated question under "Update" section.

Comment: Look at @ssteinbeck's example again. You are not using the same code, and that is why your results are different. Notice there are no quotes around `colItem` and he is using structure notation, instead of dot notation.

Comment: To overcome different table column names than struct items, you could list the columns names in the top of the SQL statement and then associate the order of the struct items in the list and loop through that. Also, if you think that my post was helpful or a solution could you mark it as such. Thanks :)