# Error Executing database query

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

What am I doing wrong here:

```
<cfquery datasource="mydb" name="qCoulmnInsert">
INSERT INTO 
           mytable (delivered_int,unique_open_int,spamreport_int,drop_int,request_int,bounce_int,deferred_int,                      processed_int,date_dt,startdate_dt,enddate_dt,open_int,blocked_int)

VALUES
      <!--- loop through your array --->
     <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(cfData)#" index="i">
     (
      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "delivered")>
        <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].delivered#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>

      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "unique_open")>
        <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].unique_open#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>


      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "spamreport")>
        <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].unique_open#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>

      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "drop")>
        <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].drop#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>


      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "request")>
        <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].request#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>


      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "bounce")>
        <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].bounce#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>

      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "deferred")>
        <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].deferred#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>

      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "processed")>
        <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].processed#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>

      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "date")>
        <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#cfData[i].date#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>

      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "startdate_dt")>
        <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#cfData[i].startdate_dt#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif> 


      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "enddate_dt")>
        <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_DATE" value="#cfData[i].enddate_dt#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif> 



      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "open")>
        <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].open#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>



      <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "blocked")>
        <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].blocked#">
      <cfelse>
         NULL
      </cfif>

      )

      <cfif i neq arrayLen(cfData)>,</cfif>
  </cfloop>
</cfquery>
```

You can refer to my previous post for more information:[inserting structure elements into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443661/inserting-structure-elements-into-database/21444627?noredirect=1#21444627)

SQL Fiddle for Table Structure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e255c/1

Where date, start and end date are datetime in my database table.

**Error Message:**

Error Executing Database Query.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5 5 5 '2014-01-06' 10 ) ( '2014-01-07' 3 ' at line 8

```
The error occurred in C:\myfile.cfm: line 55
Called from C:\application.cfc: line 386
Called from C:\myfile.cfm: line 55
Called from C:\application.cfc: line 386

53 : VALUES
54 :       <!--- loop through your array --->
55 :      <cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(cfData)#" index="i">
56 :      (
57 :       <cfif structKeyExists(cfData[i], "delivered")>
```

Comment: You forgot to post the error message. Side note, you realize the above will fail if the array is empty.

Comment: @Leigh I just posted.

Comment: Did you try not using `<cfelse>`? Just include the if

Comment: (Is that the actual error from the code you posted? I would have expected parameter markers) Anyway, you seem to be missing basic commas in between the parameter values: ie `VALUES (5 (missing) NULL (missing) ....)`. Remember, whatever CF logic you use, it still has to generate a valid sql statement.

Comment: @Leigh I updated the error after removing <cfelse>, No change at all. I just commented out `<cfelse>NULL`.

Comment: @JL Yes, I did but no change. Wondering what I am doing wrong in my above code?

Comment: @user3239126 - I did not say remove the cfelse. That was someone else. I remarked that you are missing commas in between the values, so you are **not generating valid sql**!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this comment before I posted my answer, you are right Leigh. That is it.

Comment: @GavinPickin - No worries. If I had wanted to make it an answer, I would have :)

Comment: Oh, that's a blunder mistake I did. I put the commas and it worked fine. Thanks a lot guys. I uncommented cfelse as well

Comment: By the way is there a need of last line ` <cfif i neq arrayLen(cfData)>,</cfif>` just before the cfloop ?

Comment: You could also remove the if/else and just put the code into the cfqueryparam tag: <cfqueryparam CFSQLTYPE="CF_SQL_INTEGER" value="#cfData[i].delivered#" null="#YesNoFormat(NOT structKeyExists(cfData[i], "delivered"))#">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have commas after each element / column in your query.

Your error shows it:

'5 5 5 '2014-01-06' 10 )

Add commas

'5, 5, 5, '2014-01-06', 10 )

That's the key issue.

Comment: As an aside, you should also verify the array is not empty before attempting the query. Otherwise, you will get a different SQL error when you try to run the insert.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put a comma between each value in the bracketed values section of your SQL statement.

The comma goes after each if statement so the result would be :

VALUES (NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

if you had none of your struct keys.